# how do I create templates for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, templates

when I create a new .java file it looks like this

```js
package test;

public class test {

}
```

But what if I wanted it to look like this

```js
/**
Document header blah blah blah
*/
package test;

public class test 
{
//Some default comment here blah blah
}
```

It seems that eclipse knows what to put into my file because
1. It is hard coded
OR 
2. It is contained in a text file 
OR 
3.the template is as displayed in Window->Preferences->java->code style->preferences 
(and if 3 is true that is confusing because the code style->preferences->class body entry is blank) 
Anyhow I think that if option 2 is correct and I can get my hands on that text file I could change the template to something that I like and better still I could change the package-info.java to something much better

---

It seems that maybe the this bug [Template Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318164#c6) means that I can't use templates as I would like to so the best I can do is to build a bridge and get over it

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for this is in Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates.

The overall layout for a new file is in 'Code > New Java files':

[image]

The 'Code > Class body' template defines what is in the new class body.

Comment: Thanks for that answer but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work in Eclipse Luna version 4.4.0. The problem is there is no Menu item named "Code", so I thought that maybe you meant for me to find Code > New Java files'. The 'Code > Class body' template in the filesystem where eclipse is installed but unfortunately that directory doesn't exist either. So unfortunately I am still none the wiser.

Comment: These are sections in the Code Templates preferences - added a screen shot.